# What is the best way to store a property of type object in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I have a class with properties of type object, such as:

```
public object Meta {get; set;}
```

Previously, I stored these properties without serialization, which resulted in an exception when attempting to access them due to deserialization errors. To resolve this issue, I now serialize these fields before inserting the documents into the database. This solution works well, as they are deserialized in the front-end. However, I am curious if there is a more efficient method, such as a custom serializer, that could allow these properties to be stored in the database as an object, rather than a long and unreadable string.

if we have this object for example:

```
"meta":{"description": "some long text here", "someValue" : "another long text here","anotherValue":"some really long text here"}
```

It would be quite nice and beneficial to be able to easily access and read individual fields within the meta object separately from the database.

Comment: Why is it `object`? Can it really be _anything at all_ or is the list of possibilities actually finite?

Comment: It can be anything